# Fixed sine using HP 35665A signal analyzer

Tags: signal-analysis

I would like to perform a fixed sine test at my DUT's natural frequency after finding the nat. freq. from a sine sweep test. I can see from "fixed sine" softkey under "Source" that I could have a fixed amplitude. But it is possible to have a fixed frequency instead of defining a range?

Comment: Have you considered asking the manufacturer?